# Laravel Shoppingcart installation for the pull request

Tags: laravel, github

I installed the laravel shopping cart by using composer update which is Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart as picture below:-
[image]

But the problem is under this package there don't have discount features. So I found have someone pull request under this package as picture below:-

[image]

The problem is how to I install it to add on discount features as image 2?

Comment: So you're trying to get the new update of Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart?

Comment: the 1st image doesn't have the feature, but 2nd have the feature I need, perhaps  is that any method to copy or modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside you composer.json file you can add the repo that you want the code from by doing:

```
"repositories": [
  {
  "url": "https://github.com/fraterblack/LaravelShoppingcart",

   "type": "git"
  }
],
```

Then change the package name you have for LaravelShoppingcart in composer.json require section to:

```
"require":{
    "fraterblack/LaravelShoppingcart": "dev-master"
}
```

Then run `composer update`

**(EDIT):**

Instead of what I had before, use something like this:

```
{                                                               
    "minimum-stability": "dev",                                        
    "repositories": [                                                  
        {                                                              
            "type": "git",                                             
            "url": "https://github.com/fraterblack/LaravelShoppingcart"
        }                                                              
    ],                                                                 
    "require": {                                                       
        "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "dev-master"                        
    }                                                                  
}
```

It didn't work because "frater" didn't update the composer.json file in their repo so use `"gloudemans/shoppingcart": "dev-master"` in "require" instead of `"fraterblack/LaravelShoppingcart": "dev-master"`

And instead of `composer update` just do `composer install`

Comment: may i know composer.json file  previously dont have repositories, is that just add on for this? and require part are using '"gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.5",' does it need to remove it ? or just add on "fraterblack/LaravelShoppingcart": "dev-master" ?

Comment: I tried your method, it say typo in the package name.

Comment: yes remove '"gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.5",' and add '"fraterblack/LaravelShoppingcart": "dev-master",' @lun7code

Comment: If there are no repos in your composer json then just a that repo that I mentioned anywhere in the composer.json

Comment: thanks for reply but it still have this issue  - The requested package fraterblack/laravelshoppingcart could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Comment: Yes. finally Is works. Thanks. but now the problem is the source code still remain even composer update.

Comment: You mean the source code from the last package is still showing up? @lun7code

Comment: is that possible to remove vendor and install it back ?

Comment: You can specifically remove that package by doing `composer remove gloudemans/shoppingcart` then run composer install again